# Unzip archive to an existing directory structure

Tags: linux, wordpress, shell, command-line

I'm looking at bringing the content of one WP blog over to another as I will be using WPML to serve regional content instead of multiple sites. So not strictly a WP question, more command line.

This may seem an obvious or stupid question, but if I bring over the other 'uploads' folder as a zip and unzip to the wp-content folder, will the contents merge into the existing folders or overwrite what is already there.

If it's the latter, is there a switch I can append to ensure files are merged?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `unzip` finds a file that already exists in the destination, it will ask you if you want to overwrite it. You can then type `y` to overwrite it, `A` to overwrite all files, `N` if you don't want to overwrite any of them etc.

Example:

```
$ unzip archive.zip
Archive:  archive.zip
replace foo? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

Comment: So to be clear, the directories do merge, it's just the files that may be overwritten?

Comment: the directories do merge. I just tried the following:
have a.zip and b.zip in folder /foo/
a.zip contains folder1/folder2/fileA.txt and b.zip contains folder1/folder2/foleB.txt
First extracting a.zip produces /foo/folder1/folder2/fileA.txt as expectet, subsequently unzipping b.zip leads to /foo/folder1/folder2/fileA.txt AND /foo/folder1/folder2/fileB.txt being present

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
unzip -o <filepath/zipfile.zip> -d <path where you want files>
```

Best use: unzip --help

Comment: Why is this downvoted. It seems to be the correct answer.